# Create animation of image on button

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, button

I am trying to create a library for android basically it's a indeterminate progress bar on button itself and even text next to it look the pic for reference it is inspired from snapchat

[image]

So basically i need a button with icon and text and the icon should perform animation on the button itself 
I tried using `drawableLeft` but i can't perform the animation 
I also tried using `linerlayout` with `imageView` and `textView` inside it in `xml` and then perform animation on `imageView` but since i am creating `lib` all i want is in a `class file`

So any suggestion or idea how I can solve the problem?

Comment: all UI components are extending View Group. So if u want a button like that you can create a custom View extending any View Group. Design u r button with animation inside that custom view.

Comment: Ok so basically i should create a class extending 'viewgroup' and add all the component together (imageview and textview inside linerlayout) and perform animation there for imageview ?

Comment: Yes . U got it ..... .